# Aptana doesn't create new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

I have just installed the aptana, ruby and rails. But when create a new rails project aptana does nothing, just create an empty folder. The console shows this:

> terix@localhost test]$ rails .
>   Usage:
>     rails new APP_PATH [options]
>    Options: ...

When I type (Aptana's console) "rails -v" it shows:

> Rails 4.1.6

When I type (Aptana's console) "ruby -v" it shows:

> ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux]

Is it a bug of Aptana, or I do something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: How are you creating the new project? `rails new project_name`?

Comment: In console? yes. But in aptana: File - New - Rails project

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I use GUI to create Rails project under workspace but project is empty and the code in DevKit user home directory. Aptana generate code use rails . instead of rail new. I guess the root cause may come form environment variable.

I found a workaround way: to use GUI to create Rails project and select I will generate my own code then use terminal and change directory to workspace and Type Rail new ProjectName to create Rails project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. The first problem was a name of app, i called it "test", but "test" doesn't work. Than i also installed packages (because got error) "ruby-devel" and "sqlite-devel". But I thing problem was in the name of application.